# Robot / female humanoid film

Tags: story-identification, movie, robots

I’m looking for a movie from the late 90’s early 2000’s, maybe sooner but definitely not later, that has human looking robots. I was very young, about 6, and I remember seeing two distinct scenes from this film.  Uunfortunately, I don’t have much more information to give that can help because it was so long ago.

I remember one of the girls who was a robot was walking down the stairs, then she “malfunctioned” and started walking backwards UP the stairs, as if it was going in reverse. She fell back afterwards and turned off I believe.

Then second scene I remember was at the end. It’s a little hazy but a guy's head (also a robot) was taken off and one lady was devastated and took the head and fell backwards with it. This happened at a fancy dance/ball room, so the final camera view was her holding the head and her dress spread like wings. She almost looked like a doll.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where did you see this?  Was it live-action or animated?

Comment: The title, and the robot guy head scene, reminded me of Terminator 3, although the rest doesn't match at all.

Answer (score 4):

Could this be [*The Stepford Wives*](https://www.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Stepford_Wives_(2004_film)) (2004) remake?

> The next day, Joanna, Bobbie and Roger go to Sarah's home to check up on her, where upon entering, they hear her upstairs, ecstatically screaming during sex with her husband Herb. As they scramble to sneak out, they find a remote control labeled SARAH, discovering a button that causes Sarah's breasts to enlarge and makes her walk backwards robotically.
> ...
> At the ball, the wives corner their husbands and reveal that Joanna never received the microchip implant. Mike threatens Walter, but Joanna decapitates him with a candlestick, exposing him as a robot. Mike's wife Claire explains that she created Stepford because she, too, was a bitter career-minded woman. When she discovered Mike's affair with her research assistant, she murdered them in a jealous rage. Claire then electrocutes herself by kissing Mike's severed robotic head.

The staircase scene is here (warning, NSFW audio content)

And the scene with the removal of the robot head is here

Comment: I just read through the Wikipedia plot, and it does sound like it could be the one.

Comment: @Clockwork - It absolutely is this film, but I like to pose my Story-ID answers as questions because I find you get a higher response rate from the original poster